# SyntaxError в Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

мне понадобился бот для телеграма и я нашел его на github.com

https://github.com/diflores/piazza-explorer-bot

Но он выдаёт ошибку при запуске:

```
user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ ls
bot_piazza.py  Python-3.6.4      README.md         runtime.txt
Procfile       Python-3.6.4.tgz  requirements.txt  turnos_piazza.csv

user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ python bot_piazza.py 
  File "bot_piazza.py", line 11
    TODAY = f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}"
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ python2 bot_piazza.py 
  File "bot_piazza.py", line 11
    TODAY = f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}"
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ python3 bot_piazza.py 
  File "bot_piazza.py", line 11
    TODAY = f"{datetime.datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d}"
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ python3.6 bot_piazza.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot_piazza.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

---

### В чём может быть проблема? Как исправить ошибку?

после установки pip3.6 install -r requrements.txt выдало ошибку. Я запустил через sudo и тогда всё вроде было установлено, я обновил pip install --upgrade.
Теперь похоже есть другая ошибка, это следствие не правильной установки? Хотя я не пойму, что я мог сделать не правильно.

```
   user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt 
    Collecting requests (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting apscheduler (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/34/9ef20ed473c4fd2c3df54ef77a27ae3fc7500b16b192add4720cab8b2c09/APScheduler-3.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting pandas (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/3f/f6a428599e0d4497e1595030965b5ba455fd8ade6e977e3c819973c4b41d/pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
    Collecting python-dotenv (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
    Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/63/df50cac98ea0d5b006c55a399c3bf1db9da7b5a24de7890bc9cfd5dd9e99/certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/40/a9837291310ee1ccc242ceb6ebfd9eb21539649f193a7c8c86ba15b98539/urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting six>=1.4.0 (from apscheduler->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/eb/1f97cb97bfc2390a276969c6fae16075da282f5058082d4cb10c6c5c1dba/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting pytz (from apscheduler->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/f9/f0b53f88060247251bf481fa6ea62cd0d25bf1b11a87888e53ce5b7c8ad2/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting tzlocal>=1.2 (from apscheduler->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/99/53bd1ac9349262f59c1c421d8fcc2559ae8a5eeffed9202684756b648d33/tzlocal-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apscheduler->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
    Collecting numpy>=1.13.3 (from pandas->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/20/4d43e141b5bc426ba38274933ef8e76e85c7adea2c321ecf9ebf7421cedf/numpy-1.18.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
    Collecting python-dateutil>=2.6.1 (from pandas->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting typing (from python-dotenv->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/2e/b480ee1b75e6d17d2993738670e75c1feeb9ff7f64452153cf018051cc92/typing-3.7.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: idna, certifi, chardet, urllib3, requests, six, pytz, tzlocal, apscheduler, numpy, python-dateutil, pandas, typing, python-dotenv
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
        **kwargs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
        isolated=self.isolated,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
        clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
        ensure_dir(destdir)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
        os.makedirs(path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna-2.8.dist-info'
    You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ pip3.6 install --upgrade
    You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
    You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
    user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ pip3.6 install --upgrade pip
    Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
    Collecting pip
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
        Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 544, in move
        os.rename(src, real_dst)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/pip' -> '/tmp/pip-zn5wnhh8-uninstall/usr/local/bin/pip'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
        requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
        paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
        renames(path, new_path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
        shutil.move(old, new)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 559, in move
        os.unlink(src)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/pip'
    You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


    user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ sudo pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt 
    Collecting requests (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 95kB/s 
    Collecting apscheduler (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/34/9ef20ed473c4fd2c3df54ef77a27ae3fc7500b16b192add4720cab8b2c09/APScheduler-3.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 524kB/s 
    Collecting pandas (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/52/3f/f6a428599e0d4497e1595030965b5ba455fd8ade6e977e3c819973c4b41d/pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.4MB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 10.4MB 134kB/s 
    Collecting python-dotenv (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/16/43f00b087c7f3f20a8d8dc16d6f6e2eff4e662afcb31ec4a31535a5be244/python-dotenv-0.10.5.tar.gz
      Ignoring typing: markers 'python_version < "3.5"' don't match your environment
    Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 3.6MB/s 
    Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5 (from requests->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 5.2MB/s 
    Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/63/df50cac98ea0d5b006c55a399c3bf1db9da7b5a24de7890bc9cfd5dd9e99/certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 3.3MB/s 
    Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests->-r requirements.txt (line 1))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/40/a9837291310ee1ccc242ceb6ebfd9eb21539649f193a7c8c86ba15b98539/urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 3.4MB/s 
    Collecting six>=1.4.0 (from apscheduler->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/eb/1f97cb97bfc2390a276969c6fae16075da282f5058082d4cb10c6c5c1dba/six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting pytz (from apscheduler->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/f9/f0b53f88060247251bf481fa6ea62cd0d25bf1b11a87888e53ce5b7c8ad2/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 1.8MB/s 
    Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from apscheduler->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
    Collecting tzlocal>=1.2 (from apscheduler->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/99/53bd1ac9349262f59c1c421d8fcc2559ae8a5eeffed9202684756b648d33/tzlocal-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting python-dateutil>=2.6.1 (from pandas->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227kB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 235kB 3.0MB/s 
    Collecting numpy>=1.13.3 (from pandas->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
      Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/20/4d43e141b5bc426ba38274933ef8e76e85c7adea2c321ecf9ebf7421cedf/numpy-1.18.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.1MB)
        100% |████████████████████████████████| 20.2MB 70kB/s 
    Installing collected packages: chardet, idna, certifi, urllib3, requests, six, pytz, tzlocal, apscheduler, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas, python-dotenv
      Running setup.py install for python-dotenv ... done
    Successfully installed apscheduler-3.6.3 certifi-2019.11.28 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 numpy-1.18.1 pandas-0.25.3 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-dotenv-0.10.5 pytz-2019.3 requests-2.22.0 six-1.14.0 tzlocal-2.0.0 urllib3-1.25.7
    You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.


    user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
    Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.3.1)


    user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ sudo pip3.6 install --upgrade pip
    Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
    Collecting pip
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/b6/9cfa56b4081ad13874b0c6f96af8ce16cfbc1cb06bedf8e9164ce5551ec1/pip-19.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
        Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
          Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
    Successfully installed pip-19.3.1


    user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$ python3.6 bot_piazza.py 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "bot_piazza.py", line 4, in <module>
        import pandas as pd
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
        from pandas.core.api import (
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 24, in <module>
        from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 44, in <module>
        from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 88, in <module>
        from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 70, in <module>
        from pandas.io.formats.format import DataFrameFormatter, format_percentiles
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 48, in <module>
        from pandas.io.common import _expand_user, _stringify_path
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 3, in <module>
        import bz2
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/bz2.py", line 23, in <module>
        from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
    user@user:~/Downloads/piazza-explorer-bot$
```

Comment: Установить библиотеку pandas, очевидно

Comment: Да и вообще установить все зависимости из файла requirements.txt, который вы почему-то проигнорировали

Comment: Ошибка с pandas возникает только на питоне выше 3.6. Более ранние версии питона не выдают такой ошибки с pandas. Там происходит ошибка на 11 строчке, что это может быть?

Comment: @plenin_blood, см. ответ

Comment: @plenin_blood там, очевидно, вы пытаетесь запустить код на несовместимой версии python

Comment: установил pandas и пытаюсь запуститься с python3.7 но ошибка та же  File "bot_piazza.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: @plenin_blood, ну что, похоже своими манипуляциями вы себе сломали Python 3.6. Т.к. это не системный python3, то проще всего вылечить переустановкой пакета (если бы был системный - было бы хуже). С помощью pip лучше ничего не нужно устанавливать через sudo. Если что-то не установилось из-за того что не хватило прав (pandas в данном случае) - это лечится установкой с флагом `--user`: например `pip3.6 install --user pandas`. Предложения обновить pip обычно можно игнорировать.

Answer (score 1):

1 - 3 случаи - python2 и стандартный для вашей системы python3 (какой-нибудь Python 3.4 или 3.5) ничего не знают о f-строках, они появились [начиная с Python 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

4 случай - для установленного Python 3.6 не установлена библиотека pandas. Установите все зависимости для этого интерпретатора при помощи команды
`pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt`

Если при установке возникают ошибки вида `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/idna-2.8.dist-info'` - нужно запустить установку заново с флагом `--user`:

`pip3.6 install --user -r requirements.txt`

Предложения обновить pip в большинстве случаев можно игнорировать.

Comment: Если все установили через pip3.6 (и не было никаких ошибок при установке) и запускаете через python3.6, то все должно работать.

Comment: Я обновил шапку своего поста, так как почему то выскакивает другая ошибка теперь